# How to expose an interface in web service

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I want to have a function on my WCF service with its return type as an interface, but when I call it from a client I receive a `System.Object`, not the class that implements the interface which the service sent.

Here is some sample code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello();

    [OperationContract]
    IMyObject GetMyObject();
}

public interface IMyObject
{
    int Add(int i, int j);
}

[DataContract]
public class MyObject : IMyObject
{
    public int Add(int i, int j)
    {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

In the implementation of this service I have:

```
public class LinqService : IService
{
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public IMyObject GetMyObject()
    {
        return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

`SayHello()` works well, but `GetMyObject()` returns a `System.Object`. How can change this code so that `GetMyObject()` returns an object which implements `IMyObject`?

**Edit 1**

Changed the code as follow:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SayHello();

    [OperationContract]
    IMyObject GetMyObject();
}

[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyObject))]
public interface IMyObject
{
    [OperationContract] 
    int Add(int i, int j);
}

[DataContract]
public class MyObject:IMyObject
{
    public int Add(int i, int j)
    {
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

But no success!

Comment: May I ask the purpose of returning an interface from your WCF method?

Comment: The same that you may return an i nterface from a method: Hiding implementation from user of wcf. why my wcf user should know about any class that I implemented for an interface? The user just need to know what properties or methods an object is offereing. In my example, I may return different implmentation of IMyObject based on some parameters.

Comment: Generally, That is a good intention, but rather pointless. The caller will not see any "implementation" anyway. Also having an `OperationContract` inside a `DataContract` is not supported. The two are really separate concepts. You should review [Designing Service Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Comment: Assume that my WCF needs to return a class that implemented IComparable, but at the design time stage I don't know which class I am returning and it will be decided at run time. How can I do this?

Comment: Let me put it in a simple way. The only things of a class that pass through the wire are those data members or fields that you have annotated with the DataMember attribute. Operation Contracts or methods are not passed through the wire to the client.

Comment: This is what I understand: Client call a method on interface. The web service send the request to server. The server knows that a class has been instantiated for this interface and hence it can call the method on that class. why WCF can not do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All WCF contract argument and return types have to be serializable; interfaces aren't. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108076/wcf-interface-return-type-and-knowntypes) explores the same issue with an answer revolving around the `KnownType` attribute; if you're going to be passing back various implementations of `IMyObject` I'd recommend this, otherwise you'll have to change the return type to `MyObject`.

Comment: From a pure design point of view, your question "why my wcf user should know about any class that I implemented for an interface?" is entirely valid, but unfortunately it's just a fact of the way WCF works.

Comment: Try adding `KnownType` and `ServiceKnownType` attributes, and add them to `IService` rather than `IMyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Additional Notes on Serialization
The following rules also apply to types supported by the Data Contract Serializer:

Generic types are fully supported by the data contract serializer.

Nullable types are fully supported by the data contract serializer.

**Interface types are treated either as Object or, in the case of collection interfaces, as collection types.**

.....

see full [MSDN Additional Notes on Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx)

---

**EDIT:**

I guess you are talking about Client Activated Object. To learn more about that see the following post [Returning an interface from a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288365/339204)
You see you can only send data through serialization in WCF but no implementation. The other way arround your problem is using instancing.